# Hosting files with support for file tagging / keywords

Tags: looking-for-a-script, tags, file-manager

I have a large (approx. 25GB) collection of files I would like to host online for people to  view or download. I have a spare computer I can use as a dedicated server for these files. I'm looking for a method of, or piece of software for, hosting my files where I can assign tags or keywords to the files, and people viewing my files online can search the collection via the tags.

By way of approximate solutions I've found so far, I see that there is software such as [Collectorz.com](http://www.collectorz.com/) or [Readerware](http://www.readerware.com/index.php) for creating databases of one's books / music / movies, and these databases can be searched by tags or keywords, and the databases can be made available and searchable online; this would suit my purposes except that my files are not necessarily books, music, or movies, and I want the *files themselves* accessible online, not a database describing my files.

A commercially-available solution like the ones above would be acceptable, but I'd prefer to have the whole setup under my control (i.e. I'd like to either implement it by hand, or use commercial software that doesn't rely on using the company's servers, paying them a continued fee, etc.).

The current extent of my internet experience is designing a few Google Sites, so I know there's a fair chance I won't understand the answers I receive, but I'm always happy to have a summer project :)

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple database setup with three tables in your favourite script would suffice. For example, for my website, I use an article table (your file locations), a tag table, and a table to link them. You only need to make a back-end script to connect everything, and a front-end search engine. Depending on your needs you can start out real simple.

Comment: +1, thanks for your answer! So, what is involved in a "database setup", and in writing a script? For starters, what do I need to install? If there's a tutorial for beginners somewhere you could link me to, that'd be great!

Comment: For a database setup see the thread on this forum (written by me): http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/387961/php-code-to-show-related-posts-on-a-blog